# How are WFS/WMS APIs secured?

Tags: wms, wfs, api, security, encryption

Here's a dumb question, about something I barely understand. Please forgive me if even the premise of the question is wrong.

When a WFS or WMS API is secured behind a password, is it then always also encrypted (AES-256 or likewise)?

So what I mean by that is, when you're prompted to give credentials to access an API, has the server sent encrypted traffic to you or not? Do the credentials work as a key to unencrypt the data on the client's side?

If the data sent by the server wasn't encrypted, wouldn't it be technically possible to bypass the "login" and access the unencrypted data from the server?

Comment: WMS and WFS API standards don't include any provision for securing the services.  How this is done in a service is down to the software used, and web architecture employed

Comment: In a WMS, there is no data client side, the server sends an image representation of the data.

Comment: Any encryption would be at the browser level - ssl etc, which is different from Authentication via passwords (usually using Basic security)

Comment: However, some WMS servers support KML as outputformat and then there may be lot of data client side. Excerpt from GeoServer `... <Placemark id="states.6"> <name>Colorado </name>    <description>This is the state of Colorado.  
3294394.0 people live in an area of 268659.501 square 
kilometers, and only 46983.0 take public transportation...`

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: @IanTurton I'm really only trying to get an answer to one question: How are WFS/WMS APIs secured? The reason I wrote multiple questions is to sort of lead answers closer to the level of understanding I have of the matter and to be more specific about the type of security I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 2):

They are not required to be secured in any way by the standard.

If data providers require security then it is the responsibility of the server provider to implement that security at the network, operating system or server level. How this is done in any individual system is a matter of personal choice.

Note there is a difference between authentication (loging in and proving who you are) and authorization (preventing some people from seeing data) and security/encryption (preventing onlookers seeing the data).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So do I understand correctly, that it is in theory possible to bypass authentication and access the data, provided it's unencrypted?

Comment: if there's a flaw in the authentication system then you could access data, but in general no. As I said encryption is a completely different thing